# How to add option to select list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

My select list is called `dropListBuilding`. The following code does not seem to work:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
     var val = buildings[i];
     var text = buildings[i];
     alert("value of builing at: " + i.toString() + " is: " + val);
     $("#dropListBuilding").addOption(val, text, false);
 }
```

This line dies:

```
$("#dropListBuilding").addOption(val, text, false);
```

What is the right to add items to the drop down in jQuery? I have tested without that line and the buildings variable does have my data element.

Comment: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9995132/740639

Answer (score 144):

Don't make your code so complicated. It can be done simply as below by using a foreach-like iterator:

```
$.each(buildings, function (index, value) {
    $('#dropListBuilding').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
});
```

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is the situation where you want to clear the list before populating it.

`$('#dropListBuilding').html('');`

This, in my mind, completes the answer.

Comment: @ShirleyCC only if that's what the user is looking for.  It's very possible they're looking for the value to be the same as the text itself.

Comment: I would also add that you should put the object in a var outside the loop so jquery doesn't have to find it in the dom each iteration.

Comment: How do I add the selected option?

Answer (score 19):

```
$('#dropListBuilding').append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
```

Comment: Do not add if already added? How? (i have a slide1, slide2, go back, and repeat)

Answer (score 19):

Doing it this way has always worked for me, I hope this helps.

```
var ddl = $("#dropListBuilding");   
for (k = 0; k < buildings.length; k++)
   ddl.append("<option value='" + buildings[k]+ "'>" + buildings[k] + "</option>");
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code fails because you are executing a method (addOption) on the jQuery object (and this object does not support the method)

You can use the standard Javascript function like this:

```
$("#dropListBuilding")[0].options.add( new Option("My Text","My Value") )
```

Comment: Can you point me to a reference for this method? I didn't think something like that existed, I thought the DOM method was `.options.add(`

Comment: Bob you are right, I've modified the code to use the normal JS way of adding an option

Answer (score 6):

```
$.each(data,function(index,itemData){
    $('#dropListBuilding').append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value",key)
        .text(value)); 
});
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want this pluging as it follows your existing code, maybe the plug in js file got left out somewhere.

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/

```
var myOptions = {
"Value 1" : "Text 1",
"Value 2" : "Text 2",
"Value 3" : "Text 3"
} 
$("#myselect2").addOption(myOptions, false); 
// use true if you want to select the added options » Run
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine, try out this.

```
var ob = $("#myListBox");

for (var i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
     var val = buildings[i];
     var text = buildings[i];

     ob.prepend("<option value="+ val +">" + text + "</option>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to rely on the 3.5 kB plugin for jQuery or do not want to construct the HTML string while escapping reserved HTML characters, here is a simple way that works:

```
function addOptionToSelectBox(selectBox, optionId, optionText, selectIt)
{
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = optionId;
    option.text = optionText;
    selectBox.options[selectBox.options.length] = option;
    if (selectIt) {
        option.selected = true;
    }
}

var selectBox = $('#veryImportantSelectBox')[0];
addOptionToSelectBox(selectBox, "ID1", "Option 1", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this one worked

```
success: function(data){
            alert("SUCCCESS");
            $.each(data,function(index,itemData){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(itemData));
                $("#fromDay").append( new Option(itemData.lookupLabel,itemData.id) )
            });
        }
```