# Add select options using jquery and arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, I have the really super simple stuff in jsfiddle. I am experimenting to make sure I can do it right in jquery first before I have to dynamically generate the jquery in C#. Basically the jQuery is suppose to populate an html  based on values in an array.

You can view the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/KwVty/

This is what I have so far. But its not working.

```
var makes = new array();
makes[0] = 'HOONDA';
makes[1] = 'MEETSUBITCHE';
makes[2]=  'NEWSMOBILE';
makes[3]=  'FJORD';

for(var i=0; i<makes.length; i++)
 {   
     $('#2').append('<option value=1>'+makes[i]+'</option>');
 }
```

And in the HTML:

```
<select id="2" multiple="multiple">
    <option> 10</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: The option value is 1 in all cases. Replace `/1/"+i+"/`

Comment: `Array` has an uppercase `A`, not a lowercase `a`.

Comment: 30 seconds too late you are :-P

Comment: Some advice, check your developer tools / console.  You would've seen an error about `array` not being defined.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995017/best-way-to-populate-select-list-with-jquery-json/9995132#9995132

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as `array` natively in javascript.

I think you meant to use `new Array()` (note the uppercase `A`) or `[]`

Comment: there is also `"array"`, which is the `typeof []`

Comment: @JanDvorak idk what browser you are using but in Chrome: `typeof [] ===
"object"`

Comment: ah, oops, sorry. Maybe in ES6 or ES7? :-)

Comment: Sorry about that. Been coding with very little sleep, been prone to little mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

`array`(wrong) is declared as `Array`

```
 var makes = new Array();
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/KwVty/1/