# Fill HTML dropdown box with external JSON file data

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-select

I am trying to fill a HTML Dropdown menu with data from an external JSON file, which contains the following

```
{
    "Destinations": [
    {
        "destinationName": "London",
        "destinationID": "lon"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "New York",
        "destinationID": "nyc"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "Paris",
        "destinationID": "par"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "Rome",
        "destinationID": "rom"
    }
    ]
}
```

What I would like is the drop down menu to display the destinationName, such as London, New York etc but i'm confused as how to approach this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9995132/740639

Answer (score 0):

Create a `<select>` tag in your html and fill it with `<option>` using the `value` attribute.
`Value` will be your `destinationID`, but it will show `destinationName`.

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp)

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    <select name="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$.getJSON('yourfile.json', function(data) {
    destinations = data['Destinations']

    $.each(destinations, function(id, destination) {
        destination = destination["destinationName"]
        alert(destination)
    })
});
```

It allows you to get the destination value in the destination variable, for, after, can do everything with values of this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have got the response from server like

```
{
    "Destinations": [
    {
        "destinationName": "London",
        "destinationID": "lon"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "New York",
        "destinationID": "nyc"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "Paris",
        "destinationID": "par"
    },
    {
        "destinationName": "Rome",
        "destinationID": "rom"
    }
    ]
}
```

Then your next step should be iteration of that json

```
$.each(data.Destinations, function(key, val) {
    items.append('<option value="' + val.destinationID + '">' + val.destinationName + '</option>');
  });
```

YOu can see the demo here [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa9H5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` and `append` `select` like this:

```
$.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
    $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' + v.destinationName + '</option>');
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/Mta5b/3/)**

Updated Example (test.html for http://jonathangatenby.co.uk/Candidate/json/destinations.json)

```
<select id="destinations">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="fetch">Fetch JSON</a>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fetch').click(function() {
        $.post('http://jonathangatenby.co.uk/Candidate/json/destinations.json', {}, function(data) {
            $.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
                $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' + v.destinationName + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Example to work make sure html file or the file from which you are making the `ajax` `call` are on same domain (jonathangatenby.co.uk)

Comment: Hi, on your jsFiddle example, it does gather the destinations, but how do you gather the JSON from an external file and not from the Javascript?

Comment: Change the url `'/echo/json/'` with your `url` and return the response in `json` format from the `url`

Comment: Sorry, your probably explaining this perfectly but I think i'm missing it. for example, 

http://jonathangatenby.co.uk/Candidate/json/destinations.json

Is the JSON URL file i will try and use, this would replace '/echo/json/?

Comment: Yes, But html file or the file from which you are making the `ajax` `call` should be on same `domain` http://jonathangatenby.co.uk. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, but there is still no luck im afraid. I have copied the code you have provided, but when 'Fetch JSON' is pressed, nothing is fetched. I apologise about this and appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Make sure `jQuery` reference is added `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">` and wrap the `JS` in `document` `ready` `$(document).ready(function() { // JS code here });` And try

Comment: Like so?

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">

 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#fetch').click(function() {
    $.post('http://jonathangatenby.co.uk/Candidate/json/destinations.json', {}, function(data) {
        $.each(data.Destinations, function(i, v) {
            $('#destinations').append('<option value="' + v.destinationID + '">' + v.destinationName + '</option>');
        });
    });
});
</script>

Comment: Answer updated with `jQuery` reference and `$(document).ready` Try (test.html on jonathangatenby.co.uk)