# how to create a dropdown usign jsonString object

Tags: javascript, json

I got JSON String object from backend.My Json String object contains id and en_name.Now i want to populate only en_name on my dropdown.

I ma getting this error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data..

This is my JSON String Object.

```
[{"id":2773,"environments_name":"ABC-DEF"},{"id":2770,"environments_name":"ABCS- - DSDSDSFR"
        },{"id":2774,"environments_name":"GFDSS - GGGDFF"}] .



        //this my ajax call 
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#customerDetails").change(function() {
                    var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'GET',
                        url : 'environments',
                        data : {
                            selectedcustomername : value1
                        },
                        success : function(result) {
                            getEnvNames(result);
                       }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

    //this is my function 
        <script language="JavaScript">
        function getEnvNames(result){
            alert("inside the function");
            var item= result;
            alert("rowwwww>>>>"+row);
            var select="<select id='environmentName'>";
            for(var i=0,i=row.length;i>1;i++){
                 var item=JSON.parse(row[i]);
                alert("for loop");
                 var item=row[i];
```

//Here I am getting item value is undefined.

```
                  alert("itemmmmmmmm>>>"+item);
                  alert("row[i],,,,,,>>>"+row[i]);
                  select+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.name+"</option>";
                } 
                select+="</select>";

                document.write(select);
        }
        </script>

        This is my JSP

        <td aligh="right">Select Environemnt : <select
                            name="environmentName" id="environmentName">
                            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>
                            </select></td></tr>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760866/fill-html-dropdown-box-with-external-json-file-data

Answer (score 0):

Change `getEnvNames(result);` to `getEnvNames(JSON.parse(result));`

Remove var `item=JSON.parse(row[i]);` from the processing loop

Comment: getEnvNames(JSON.parse(result));..i write like this,I am printing the value of result in my new method.I am getting relult  is                                        [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

Comment: My JSp is not recogsing JSON Keyword.

Comment: That is correct because you are retrieving 4 objects. The browser will only show that they are objects and not the contents of the objects. When you loop through the objects - what happens?

Comment: item is undefined i am getting