# Populate select box dynamically based on user prompts (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

If a user enters a value(s) (via javascript prompt), and that value is stored in a changing array, is there a way to automatically update a select box in an HTML form with the value(s) that the user enters?  I ask because I am fairly new to jquery and front-end design, and I'm not certain if this can be done after a page is loaded.

I appreciate the help from the two people who responded, and I would upvote both of your answers as helpful, but I do not have enough reputation yet.

To clarify my question a bit better, what I would like to see happen is a select box automatically filled with values, based on user prompts.

For example, if I have

```
var r = true;
while(r == true){
var path = window.prompt("Please enter path here"); 
//I would like to put <option>path</option> inside a selection box
var r = confirm("Enter another path?");
}
```

If this is not entirely possible, I understand, but that's why I asked the question in the first place.

EDIT:

Found a solution here
[How to add option to select list in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730360/how-to-add-option-to-select-list-in-jquery)

Comment: Well, I'm up-voting because I enjoyed the challenge. And I do think it's a useful question and resource (albeit, obviously, this is at least *partially* motivated by self interest).

Answer (score 1):

So, I got kind of bored for a little while; that being the case, may I offer you this:

```
var startValues = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'];

function childElementType(node) {
    var props = {
        childType: '',
        textType: Node.textContent ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        hasValue: false
    };
    switch (node.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'select':
            props.childType = 'option';
            props.hasValue = true;
            break;
        case 'ol':
        case 'ul':
            props.childType = 'li';
            break;
    }
    return props;
}
Object.prototype.populate = function (values) {
    if (this.length) {
        return this;
    } else {
        var child = childElementType(this),
            newChild;
        for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
            newChild = document.createElement(child.childType);
            newChild[child.textType] = values[i];
            if (child.hasValue) {
                newChild.value = newChild[child.textType];
            }
            this.appendChild(newChild);
        }
    }
    return this;
};

Object.prototype.addTo = function (message) {
    var control = document.createElement('button'),
        that = this;
    control.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message || '+ add to ' + that.tagName.toLowerCase()));
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(control, this.nextSibling);
    var child = childElementType(this);

    function addNew() {
        var text = prompt('Add the new entry:'),
            newEntry;
        if (text) {
            newEntry = document.createElement(child.childType);
            newEntry[child.textType] = text;
            that.appendChild(newEntry);
        }
    }
    control.onclick = addNew;
    return this;
};

document.getElementById('select').populate(startValues).addTo();
document.getElementById('ul').populate(startValues).addTo();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YDgCK/1/).

You can also pass a default message in to the `addTo()` method, to give specific text to the created buttons and, because each method returns the `this` object/node, you can call them in either order (so long as, obviously, you select the elements *first*), for example *both* these approaches are valid and usable:

```
document.getElementById('select').addTo('Moar options..?').populate(startValues);
document.getElementById('ul').populate(startValues).addTo('Go on, add more!');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YDgCK/3/).

References:

- [Conditional ('ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement).createTextNode
- [`document.createTextNod()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode).
- [`for (...) {}` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.textContent).
- [`switch () {...}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).
- [`window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt).

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work. This way will overwrite existing options, but it is possible to append them to already existing ones.

```
$("#saveButton").on("click", function(){
    var options = '';

    for ( var item in optionsArray ){
        options += "<option>" + item +"</option>";
    }    

    $('#selectbox').html(options)
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njgray/BM8KL/