# Populate Select list with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

So I am a real JQUERY novice, so please go easy on me.

I would like to populate a CFSELECT using data returned from a CFC. Here is my working CFC:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="getDescriptions" access="remote" returnformat="json" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfquery name="customDescriptions" datasource="#datasource#">
        select description
        from service_descriptions
        where description <>"ADD NEW"
        order by description
     </cfquery>

    <cfset data = serializeJSON(customDescriptions)>
    <cfreturn data>
</cffunction>
```

**Here is how the data from my CFC is returned:**

> ---->Choose from the list<----Backup MaintenanceMalware RemovalMonthly Server MaintenanceNetwatch Alert - High CPU usageNetwatch Alert - Low
>   Disk space on CNetwatch Backup AlertNew Employee TrainingPerform
>   monthly tune-ups on workstationsTesttest2test3test4test5Weekly
>   MaintenanceWhite-list Request

I am strugling with my AJAX code to populate my CFSELECT form element.

```
<cfselect name="descriptionDD4" id="descriptionDD4">
   <option value="add_new">ADD NEW</option>
</cfselect>
```

Here is what I have so far with my AJAX but it doesn't work.

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function CheckAjaxCall()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'cfcs/get_descriptions.cfc?method=getDescriptions',                    
                    dataType:'json',
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(customDescriptions){ 

                $('##descriptionDD4').get(0).options.length = 0;
                $('##descriptionDD4').get(0).options[0] = new Option("--Select--", "0");        

                $.each(description, function(i,item) {
                                    $('##descriptionDD4').get(0).options[$('##descriptionDD4').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item[i].Name, item[i].roll);
                                                                                                                    // Display      Value
                            });

                            },
                            //error:function(){alert("Connection Is Not Available");}
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
            </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
-Brian

Comment: There is a much easier way to populate your cfselect.  Just use ColdFusion. No json, ajax, javascript, other any other complications required.

Comment: @Brian - `<cfselect>` is just a wrapper for a plain html select, that includes some unwieldy UI code based on a *different* (and older) javscript library than jQuery.  Since you are using jQuery, ditch the `<cfselect>` and use `<select>` instead.

Comment: Yes I know that using the bind or query feature of CFSELECT is easier, however I need to refresh the data in this CFSELECT when some other element on this page is posted via an AJAX call (without a page refresh). My goal is to refresh it by calling the function that populates it when a different AJAX post is successful. I feel I'm pretty close with code right?

Comment: The code you have written does not need `cfselect` so stop using it. You should avoid using ANY CF UI elements, they are riddled with issues, poor implementation and limited functionality. The likely problem is that you are not returning the data in a format that is expected. Just JSON-ing a query is rarely - if ever - the format that would be expected on the client side. Take a look at the data being returned using Chrome Dev Tools or FireBug in Firefox to see what I mean.

Comment: @Leigh - Understood, I'll change it to a standard <select> tag. Didn't improve my results BTW.

Comment: Also, in your function, you have `returnformat="JSON"` and then you are serializing the data before returning it. Get rid of the `serializeJSON()` call and just return `customDescriptions`. OR get rid of both and add `returnFormat=json` to the AJAX call itself. This way the function can server multiple purposes.

Comment: @Scott - I made your suggested changes. Strange thing is that I am not even seeing the get_description.cfc in my Network Tab in the Chromoe developer tools. Could my JavaScript not be firing? I just have my <script> tag right above my <select> tag. IS that the proper place?

Comment: @BrianFleishman - It was not supposed to fix the problem ;-) Just pointing out that it is not needed. As Scott mentioned, CF uses a silly format for serializing queries.  Run the method in your browser to understand what is actually returned: `http://yourserver/cfcs/get_descriptions.cfc?method=getDescriptions&returnFormat=json` . Also, javascript is case sensitive. So even if your ajax is firing, using `data` or `description` (lower case) would not work anyway because CF (unfortunately) converts the structure keys to all upper case ie `DATA` or `DESCRIPTION`.

Comment: I updated my question with my modified AJAX. I now see the code running in my console and it is returning data from CFC. Here is the format of the data: ---->Choose from the list<----Backup MaintenanceMalware RemovalMonthly Server MaintenanceNetwatch Alert - High CPU usageNetwatch Alert - Low Disk space on CNetwatch Backup AlertNew Employee TrainingPerform monthly tune-ups on workstationsTesttest2test3test4test5Weekly MaintenanceWhite-list Request

Comment: @BrianFleishman please update your question [edit] with these additional details instead of posting to comments. They will be easier to read that way.

Comment: No prob. My questions is up to date at this point.

Comment: @BrianFleishman - It sounds like you did not fully incorporate [Scott's comments about the cffunction](http://stackoverflow.com/users/789209/scott-stroz). For the greatest flexibility, just have your function return a `query`. Do not use serializeJSON, just return the query variable as is. The signature should be `<cffunction name="getDescriptions" access="remote" returntype="query">. When you call the function from jQuery, be sure to add `&returnFormat=json` to the URL. That tells CF encode the query results as JSON.

Comment: ok, I've posted my updated CFC and AJAX. My selectlist now shows "--Select--" as my only option.

Comment: @BrianFleishman - FYI, Stack Overflow uses a Q&A (Question and Answer format). If you overwrite the original "non-working" code, the subsequent comments and answers no longer make sense. It is preferable to post "working" versions as a separate answer or *append* the example as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The way CF serializes queries by default is wonky. In the long run you may want to roll-your-own and return something more typical (and intuitive), like an array of structures. But it is still worthwhile to understand *why* your current code is not working, IMO.

**Issue:**

As [Scott pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553467/populate-cfselct-with-ajax/25576481#comment39902799_25553467), the biggest problem is that your javascript code is expecting one format, but your cfc is returning a different format. You need to change one of them, so they are both in synch. Also, as I mentioned in the comments, using `cfselect` does not buy you anything here, so just use a plain html `select` instead.

**Debugging:**

Before you can do anything with the response from the CFC, you need to understand the format of what it is sending back. Start simply. Just call the `cffunction` when the page loads and log the response to the console. You can wrap everything up in a function later, after it is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Important: Must append the parameter "&returnformat=json"
    $.ajax({
       url: 'cfcs/get_descriptions.cfc?method=getDescriptions&returnformat=json'
       , dataType: 'json'
       , success: function(response){
           console.dir(response);
       },
       error: function(msg){
           console.log(msg);
       }
    })
}); 
</script>
```

Using FF's web console, you will see the result is a structure containing two keys: `COLUMNS` and `DATA`. 
[image: Firefox Web Console]

`DATA` is a multi-dimensional array, containing your query results. It is indexed by row and column number. You can loop through it, same as in CF. The only difference is the index will be zero based (and of course key names are case sensitive in JS). Add the code below to your `success` function and you will see the query values displayed in the Web Console.

```
 // display values for debugging purposes
 for (var i = 0; i < response.DATA.length; i++){
    console.log("value in row ["+ i +"] column [0] = "+ response.DATA[i][0]);
 }
```

**Usage:**

Once you understand how to access the data, it is just a matter of using it to populate the list. You can either use the `for` loop to append options individually, or plug the `DATA` array into the `$.each` function, using [the method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942189/104223). Since your query only returns a single column, I used it for both the option text and value.

```
$.each(response.DATA, function(i, row){
            // get value in first column ie "description"
            var description = row[0];

            // append new option to list
            $("#descriptionDD4").append($('<option/>', { 
                    value: description,
                    text : description 
            }));
        });
```

All that is left is to wrap the ajax call in a function you can call wherever needed. But you should be able to figure that part out on your own.

Hopefully this shed a little light on working with remote cffunctions from jQuery.

Comment: Thanks so much Leigh for the insight. I'll work on this and report back.

Comment: This works perfectly, and I think I'm starting to get it a bit now. A little bit of effort on your part goes a long, long way for a newbie like me. Thank you again for taking the time to provide such a detailed explanation!

Comment: I have posted my working AJAX code. I changed it from an anonymous function to a custom one so I could call it from other code. So to call this function from the success code of another AJAX call, I would just use PopulateSelectLists(); in the success section correct?

Comment: Better to wrap the entire `$.ajax` block in a *separate* function, outside `$(document).ready(...)`. Then invoke that function when the page loads, ie inside `.ready`, and whenever you need to refresh the list.