# Set drop down option value using jquery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add options to a drop down list dynamically as per the integer value of a variable

this is my html code of dropdown list

```
<select class="inputreq" id="qty" name="qty"><option value="1">1</option></select>
```

Like below i am getting integer value at run time

```
var optioneValue = <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_max_qty_limit')%>
```

Suppose if optioneValue is 3 i want to display 3 options in dropdown list like this

```
<select class="inputreq" id="qty" name="qty">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I have tried with javascript but its not working..I am new to this can we achieve this using jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
while ( i <= <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_max_qty_limit')%> ) {
var addSelectOption = document.getElementById('qty');
addSelectOption.options[i-1]= new Option(i,i);
i++; // Increment i
}
</script>
```

Comment: See the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730360/how-to-add-option-to-select-list-in-jquery

Comment: hope this will help http://jsfiddle.net/3908050/trdo0z5v/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i;
    for( i=1; i <= <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_max_qty_limit')%>; i++ ) {
        $('<option/>',{
              value:i,
              text:i
        }).appendTo("#qty");
    }
</script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hn3s18q/)

Answer (score 0):

use **[lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** selector in jquery

```
var optioneValue = 3;  // example 
$("#qty option").hide();
$("#qty option:lt(" + optioneValue + ")").show();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sL5pata4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try that code

```
<select class="inputreq" id="qty" name="qty">
<%=
    var i = 1;
    while ( i <= getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_max_qty_limit')) {
        var addSelectOption = document.getElementById('qty');
        addSelectOption.options[i-1]= new Option(i,i);
        i++; // Increment i
    }
%>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<select class="inputreq" id="qty" name="qty">
<?php
     for($i=1;$i<=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_max_qty_limit');$i++)
     {
          echo '<option value="'.$i .'">'.$i.'</option>';
     }
?>
</select>
```