# javascript does not bind the data to HTML Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I've this select element of html5 or Dropdown. I'm using c# to fetch data from database which it is getting correctly. when I try to bind that data fetched from db to select element using java script it just don't do that. I can get all the UserNames in a java script variable but when I try to bind that to dropdown/select element it just does not appear

My C# Method in MVC controller is

```
 public JsonResult GetUsersList()
    {
       // var userList= new List<>
        var userList = _db.UserInfromations.ToList();
        return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My select element

```
<select id="userDropDown" required name="userDropDown"></select>
```

and my java script I'll add my all tries that I've don so far.. created separate function for success and all but noting works

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   // debugger;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/User/GetUsersList",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            var userName = data.UserName;
            $("#userDropDown").val(userName);
            return false;
        })
        .error(function () {
            window.ajaxErrorMessage();
        });
}(jQuery));
```

The separate Success function

```
 function displayUser(response) {
    var getData = response;
    if (getData.length > 0) {
        var user = "";
       // user = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
            user += " " + getData[i].UserName ;
        }
       // $("#userDropDown").val(user);
        $("#userDropDown").text(user);
        //$("#userDropDown").html(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: use console.log on success and check what response is coming

Comment: did you placed your user data within <option></option> tags..

Comment: As I said it gets the data but This section does not bind that data
 // $("#userDropDown").val(user);
        $("#userDropDown").text(user);
        //$("#userDropDown").html(user);

Comment: Your sending back a array of `UserInfromations`. You cannot set the value of a dropdownlist to an array of complex objects. Are you trying to add options to the dropdownlist based on the values of each `UserInfromations`?

Comment: how does your json object looks?

Comment: Yes @StephenMuecke as you can see I just want to get user name , the method of c# works fine

Comment: You must create options-tags. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Comment: I also get a proper JSON responce
http://prntscr.com/95wegs
@madalinivascu

Comment: But do you ant to add an `<option>` element for each item in the collection?

Comment: No haven't used the <option>

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for generating options. But do not send back `_db.UserInfromations.ToList();` - instead just send what you need - e.g. `_db.UserInfromations.Select(x => x.UserName);`

Comment: I posted an answer (before the other guy BTW), and it should work, let me know if it doesn't.   Please see here about how to accept an answer on StackOverflow ...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thanks @NotoriousPet0 thank you for your help

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 you didn't post full answer, happens to the best of us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add option to select list in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730360/how-to-add-option-to-select-list-in-jquery)

Comment: I'm really sorry for that let me get some marks and I'll give you up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a option tag for each json object from your array then select the property of each object 
try:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       // debugger;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/User/GetUsersList",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        })
            .success(function (data) {
               $.each(data,function(i,v){
                  $("#userDropDown").append($('<option/>', { 
            value: v.Id,
            text : v.UserName 
        })); 
    })

            })
            .error(function () {
                window.ajaxErrorMessage();
            });
    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Well this has done some thing but I can't see any thing the dropdown is still empty do i need to add <option> tag within <select> tag or will work without it

Comment: what is that I was doing wrong can i get an answer for that

Comment: you need to append a option tag for each json object from your array and you are getting the keys wrong

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add it as an `<option>` to the select box.  You also may need to parse the json.

Replace this ...   `$("#userDropDown").val(userName);` with the code below:

```
$("#userDropDown").append($('<option/>', { 
        value: userName,
        text : userName 
}));
```

for multiple additions, use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).  You made need to also `JSON.parse(data)` to get it in the right format.

```
$.each(userName, function (index, value) {
    $('#userDropDown').append($('<option/>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value 
    }));
});
```